# Number of connected components of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $F$ be the set of all irrational numbers in $\mathbb {R}$. $X=\mathbb {R^2}(F×F )$ with the usual subspace topology of $\mathbb {R^2}$.Number of connected components of $X$?

I know only that if $A$ is countable then $\mathbb{R^n}A$ is connected. But how that will help me . Please help.

Comment: what is $\mathbb R^2(F  \times F)$?

Comment: I assumed it was $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus (F \times F)$, I will delete my answer if this is not the case.

Comment: @Nick L that's true

Answer (score 1):

Write $X = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R} \cup  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Since $X$ is covered by lines in both coordinate directions,  it is path connected. In particular $X$ has one connected component.